# SQL string escape to prevent sql injection

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

Normally when I do a sql statement I use the following format so the params are automatically escaped:

```
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

However, I am building a "SQL-builder" and I need to have very fine control over the string that is being constructed. An example pattern I have is:

```
for field, value in d.items():
    sql_where_caluse += "AND %s='%s' " % (field, value)
```

`value` will be a string. Are there any built-in python tools to "SQL-safe" an input string? Most basically, it should escape the enclosing quote, but of course a more sophisticated one should do a lot more than that. What could I use for that?

Comment: Do you know the table ahead of time? Can you compare `field` with what's in the table definition. (Also aside you obviously can't do multiple `WHERE` statements).

Comment: SQL injection has less to do with "escaping" and more to do with simply not executing user-modifiable values as code.  So just don't use the user-entered values in your code.  Compare them with a known white-list of possible column/table/etc. names (which can be dynamically determined from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` if need be).  If a match is found, use that known value.  If it isn't found, return an error.

Comment: we need to verify that `field` is valid for inclusion in the sql text, and doesn't need to be escaped (enclosed in backticks), sql injection.  personally, i would interpolate just the column name, and leave a `%s` placeholder in the sql, e.g.  `sql += " AND  %s = %%s" % (field,)` and then append `value` to the `params` array, and when we're done dynamically appending, we can just do the same `.execute(sql, params)` like normal

Comment: When I coded SQL builders for several projects, I always ended up constructing an object representing parameters separately from the SQL string. I would add a parameter placeholder to the SQL string and the parameter value to my parameters object. At the end I would pass the collected parameter values to the query for binding inside the SQL driver, along with the SQL query string that I built dynamically. This is the way that gives you the ultimate safety.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that sounds like a great idea. Would you want to show an example of that in an answer?

Comment: @David: in the sql string append, replace `='%s'` with `=%%s`, so the sql will contain a literal `=%s`.  don't pass in the value, but on another line, append `value` onto the `params` array, whatever pattern you want to use for that, e,g,   `params.append(value)`  then when we're ready to execute the SQL, we can use the same  `.execute(sql,params)` pattern

Comment: @David542 I wish I could, but I don't know Python. I coded up the same approach in Java and in C#, though, so I am pretty certain this could be done in Python as well. In C# I kept my parameters in a dictionary of string to object, with string representing the parameter name I was generating as I was building my SQL string (`param0`, `param1`, `param2`, etc.) In Java, which does not support named parameters, I added parameter values to a list in the same order as they were used in the SQL.